# Send Automatic Email on filemaker

Tags: filemaker

Does anyone know how to send an automatic email in filemaker pro 14?
Or can I use any language like python in filemaker to create a trigger to automatically send an email? 
For example if I have completed a record on my system or meet the deadline it will automatically send an email

Comment: This question would be much better suited to one of the FileMaker forums than here.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

> can I use any language like python in filemaker

No, FileMaker has its own "language".

> For example if I have completed a record on my system...

To have something happen automatically as a result of user performing some action, look at [script triggers](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/create_layout.9.69.html#1106226).

> ... or meet the deadline it will automatically send an email

"Meet the deadline" is not an event that FileMaker will react to. And you would not want to have it that way, because then nothing would happen if the deadline were met while the file was closed.

I would suggest you do this as part of your opening script: find the records that have passed their deadline, process them and make a note of either the records processed or the timestamp, so that you don't process them again next time.